# Search for a filename on remote server. If found, send its name to host server

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, localhost, remote-server

I'm starting with `python3` and stuck with following problem. I will be thankful for any help to unblock me.

**Requirement:**

1. run python script on host server to do following:
2. from host server, ssh to a remote server.
3. search for a file if its present on the remote server.
4. if present, send its name to the host server.
5. else, print following on host server `"file not found on remote server"`.

**Sample code:**

```
import sys
import getopt
import os
from os import path
import re
import copy
import getpass
import time
import socket
import re

bin_ver = "1.99"
chip = "6233"

remote_bin_path = "/path/of/the/binary/release/v"+bin_ver+"/bin/"
print("path of binary on remote server is " + remote_bin_path)

os.getcwd()
os.chdir(remote_bin_path) 
os.getcwd()

if (chip == "6233" or chip == "62334"):
    sub_ver = "ab"
else:
    sub_ver = "xy"

print("sub_ver is: " + sub_ver)

search_string = "*" + chip + "*" + sub_ver + "*"
print("search_string is " + search_string)
cmd = "ls -1 " + search_string
print("cmd is " + cmd)

required_file = os.popen(cmd).read()
print("INFO: required file is \n"+required_file)
```

**Input dataset: sample file names present on remote server:**

```
binary-v1.99-6233b0-ab-cde-1.2.3.bin
binary-v1.99-62334a0-xy-cde-1.2.3.bin
binary-v1.99-62334b0-ab-cde-1.2.3.bin
binary-v1.99-62334a0-xy-cde-1.2.3.bin
binary-v1.99-6278b0-ab-cde-1.2.3.bin
binary-v1.99-6277a0-ab-cde-1.2.3.bin
```

**Problem with above implementation:**

This code runs fine on the host server, but the issue is it returns 2 file names:

```
binary-v1.99-6233b0-ab-cde-1.2.3.bin
binary-v1.99-62334b0-ab-cde-1.2.3.bin
```

Since the input variable `chip = "6233"`, i do not want the output corresponding to `62334`. How to set the correct word boundary for `6233` in `search_string` variable?

**Next Setps:**

How can I run this script on the remote server and return the filename to the host server.